# VB.NET display letters of a word under eachother in a label

Tags: vb.net, string

Dim intLength, intTeller As Integer
        Dim strBack, strText As String

```
    strText = txtInvoer.Text
    intLength = txtInvoer.Text.Length



    For intLength = 1 To intLength

        lblLetterPerLetter.Text &= strText.Substring(0, intLength) & vbCrLf
    Next

    For intTeller = 0 To strText.Length - 1
        lblOnderMekaar.Text &= strText.Chars(intTeller).ToString
    Next
```

How do i display let's say my name under eachoter?
Ex.

S

H

A

W

N

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
lblLetterPerLetter.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, "SHAWN".AsEnumerable())
```

You need to use `AsEnumerable()` to treat the `String` as `IEnumerable(Of Char)`, otherwise it's treated as a single `String`. You could also declare it as `IEnumerable(Of Char)` in the first place:

```
Dim nameChars As IEnumerable(Of Char) = "SHAWN"
lblLetterPerLetter.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, nameChars)
```